# How to use deployment project properties in post build events?

Tags: windows-installer, post-build-event

Having a VDPROJ project to produce an installer, a post build event is required to have some properties on the project. For example it's a batch file used to rename the MSI final installer file and include the target platform in it. Eg. it's required to be run like this:

```
ren Behnama.msi Behnama_$(TargetPlatform).msi
```

But TargetPlatform is a property of the project. How can I make it available for the batch file? I also tried using Behnama_$(TargetPlatform) for both ProductName and Title with no success.

How can I include target platform in MSI installer's name?

Comment: Is VD == VB (Visual Basic .NET)?

Comment: Certainly not...

Answer (score 0):

To get the platform from your project, you can just use `$(var.Platform)`. The platform will be x86 or x64, depends on your configuration manager.

WXS-file or WXI-file

```xml
<!-- 32 bit vs. 64 bit -->
<?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
  <?define Win64 = "yes" ?>
<?else ?>
  <?define Win64 = "no" ?>
<?endif ?>
```

In the project file `MyProduct.wixproj` you can define the output path

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>.\bin\x86\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>Debug</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

It is always better to use folders for the platform instead of filenames. Because the `obj` folder can be reused, when you change the platform.

Comment: Note that it's not a WXS or WXI project. It's a VDPROJ.